# Cardinality of variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to show that the cardinality of any variety of positive dimension is $ |k |$ where $k $ is the field being considered. This is part of exercise I.4.8 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

> Show that any variety of positive dimension over $k $ has the same cardinality as $ k $. Hints: Do $\mathbb{A}^{n} $ and $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ first. Then for any $ X $, use induction on the dimension $ n $. Use (4.9) to make $ X $ birational to a hypersurface $ H \subset\mathbb{P}^{n+1 }$. Use (Ex. 3.7) to show that the projection of $  H$ to $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ from a point not on $ H$ is finite-to-one and surjective.

So far I successfully showed this result for $ \mathbb{A}^{ n} $ and $ \mathbb{P}^{ n} $. For the general case, since $ X$ sits in a projective space, we have $|X | \le | k| $. To show the opposite inquality, $ X $ has an affine open subset $ U $of positive dimension. Hence there is a nonconstant polynomial as a regular function on $ U $. If I show that this polynomial is surjective, I'm done. I'm unable to show this so far.

I'm interested in completing my approach. If it's hopeless or too difficult, I'm fine with a solution following the hint of the book.

Thank you

Comment: Rereading their sketch, induction isn't used at all in the part they describe: it is simply reducing the general case to the case of projective space. The need for induction will appear when working through the details of using the reduction to compute the cardinality.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for your comment. Even ignoring induction, I don't know how birationality with a hypersurface in the projective space helps. Is it somehow possible to show that an open subset of the hypersurface has cardinality $ |k |$? This seems to me the same question I'm trying to prove, and no reduction of dimension happens. I would appreciate a more detailed answer, if possible.

Comment: The proof sketch wants you to compare the cardinality of a variety with the cardinality of a *projective space*, so you can use what you've already proven about projective space.

Comment: @Hurkyl The birational map allows me to compare the cardinality of an open set in the given variety with an open set in the projective space. I don't know (yet) what the cardinality of the latter open set is. However, I think I have a better idea: The variety $X$ contains an open affine set $U$. $U$ has a surjective regular function (for example : projection on first coordinate). Hence $|X| \ge |k|$. Does this make sense?

Comment: What about using the Noether Normalization Lemma to obtain a finite surjective map to some affine space from your open set $U$?

Comment: @RobertAuffarth I didn't know about the geometric statement of this lemma. It looks like it can be used indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach runs into the difficulty of showing surjectivity of any nonconstant regular function. However, it can be made to work after some tweaks:

It suffices to show that an affine variety $U$, with $\dim U > 0$, has $|U| \ge |k|$. A morphism $U \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ is the same as an element of the coordinate ring $A(U) = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I(U)$. Since $k = \overline{k}$ and $\dim U = \dim A(U) > 0$, there exists $f \in A(U)$ transcendental over $k$, i.e. $\phi^* : k[x] \to A(U), x \mapsto f$, is an injection. Then $\phi : U \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ is dominant (in fact, $\phi(U)$ contains a nonempty open set), so $|\mathbb{A}^1_k \setminus \phi(U)| < \infty \implies |U| \ge |\phi(U)| = |\mathbb{A}^1_k| = |k|$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Yes, as mentioned in the comments. I wanted to avoid the full strength though :)

Comment: Oops! I missed that conversation. Apologies. :)

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. I see why $\varphi$ is dominant since $\varphi^*$ is injective. but why is $\varphi(U)$ an open set? The density of $\varphi(U)$ alone isn't sufficient to conclude that $|\mathbb{A}^{1} \setminus \varphi(U)| < \infty$, right?

Comment: @PeterM: One (admittedly high-powered) way to see that $\phi(U)$ contains a nonempty open set is by Chevalley's Theorem, which guarantees that $\phi(U)$ is constructible. Now any dense constructible subset of an irreducible Zariski space (which $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is) contains a nonempty open set

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand the part of the density of $\phi(U)$ can you explain a little more?